# WFFM Error - An Item with the same key has already been added

Tags: wffm

On my local environment all WFFM forms are working ok, however on our test environment when any form is submitted we get the error:

## An item with the same key has already been added.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 24:     if (!IsPost)
Line 25:     {
Line 26:       queryString.Add("wffm." + Constants.FormItemId, Model.Item.ID.ToGuid());
Line 27:       queryString.Add("wffm." + Constants.Id, Model.UniqueId);
Line 28:     }
```

**Source File:** D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Form\EditorTemplates\FormViewModel.cshtml    Line: 26

**Note:** I have tried uncehcking the field on the form `Is Ajax Mvc Form` and this seems to resolve the issue.

Is there some configuration setting which could be causing this, since there is no difference in the form content itself between the two environments.

Comment: You seem to be adding the query string key "wffm." twice.

Comment: That's not my code BTW, its the MVC rendering used by WFFM. Also the code is using "wffm." + Constants.FormItemId so it is appending the ID of the form to the end of the query string.

Comment: check if some earlier code is adding a query string with the key `"wffm." + Constants.FormItemId` - that is the line it is failing on. Also - what are the values of `Constants.FormItemId` and `Constants.Id` - do they come from config or hard coded values?

Comment: Sorry Matthew, I completely missed the concatentaion. Must be going blind. As @RichardSeal says, check there's not something appended already, and check the constants.

Comment: do you have url rewriting on test environment?

Comment: @RichardSeal the stacktrace info in my question relates to the built-in WFFM renderings. Maybe I still need to debug that though...

Comment: @SitecoreClimber we do, but just IIS url rewrite stuff for whitelisting IP addresses. No actual page re-writes or redirects.

Comment: can you verify if this one is the problem? enable url rewrite locally and try to see if it's working.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber it turned out that the problem _was_ related to redirects, but not redirects from the url rewrite module, it was a 404 handler which was intercepting too many requests.

Comment: Cool, I saw this problem before but it is hard to find real solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue turned out to be due to a custom 404 error handler ([Sitecore Climber](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/14/sitecore-climber) was on the right track when he mentioned about the IIS rewrite module - **redirects can mess up WFFM!**). It was intercepting requests (with a `httpRequestBegin` pipeline handler) and returning the 404 page content. The solution was to change the 404 handler to ignore requests where the URL started with `/form`.

Note: if you create a 404 handler, make sure it can ignore certain paths where a sitecore item is not resolved, otherwise you will break lots of things in Sitecore!

Comment: we had a custom item resolver which was taking the /formbuilder url (after submitting the form) and redirecting to itself by lowering the URL, due to this same URL was being hit twice and was causing the same query string to be added twice hence causing the error "Item with the same key has already been added"